# How to import python module given a certain directory structure

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import the api module given the directory structure below.

/usr/local/bin/confluence-python/confluence/api.py

/usr/local/bin/ is the correct path, so that is not an issue.

The issue I'm having I think is that this library was forked by someone on github, the name of the repo was changed, but the documentation was not changed to reflect that (if that makes sense).

The documentation shows an example that has:

```
from confluence-python import api
```

This errors out because api can't be found.

This feels like a dumb question, but how do I import api in this example?

Comment: include that directory in your `sys.path`, then import it

Comment: Did you install this package in `bin`? Normally python libraries are installed by a package manager (pip) and go in `lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` and will automatically be included in your PYTHONPATH when importing modules.

Comment: Does it fail because it can't find `api`, or because it can't find `confluence-python`?

Comment: Open a shell and import `confluence-python` and then run `dir(confluence-python)`. what you're looking for will probably be listed in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `api` does not live under `confluence-python`, but under `confluence-python/confluence`, you need to point to it directly.  You go down the directory structure using the dot notation:

```
from confluence-python.confluence import api
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answers my question, but it did not end up resolving the issue, for some reason I get ImportError: no module confluence.